# Sum of (at most) 5 primes

Tags: code-golf, math, primes

Terence Tao [recently proved](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/every-odd-integer-larger-than-1-is-the-sum-of-at-most-five-primes/) a weak form of Goldbach's conjecture!  Let's exploit it!

Given an odd integer `n > 1`, write `n` as a sum of up to 5 primes.  Take the input however you like, and give output however you like.  For example,

```
def g(o):
    for l in prime_range(o+1):
        if l == o:
            return l,
        for d in prime_range(l+1):
            for b in prime_range(d+1):
                if l+d+b == o:
                    return l,d,b
                for c in prime_range(b+1):
                    for h in prime_range(c+1):
                        if l+d+b+c+h == o:
                            return l,d,b,c,h
```

is Sage code that takes an integer as input, and returns a list of integers as output whose sum is `n`.  By Tao's theorem, this will always terminate!

**Input**

An odd integer `n`.  You decide how to take the input, but if it's weird, explain it.

**Output**

Rather open-ended.  Return a list.  Print a string.  Gimme one, a few, or all.  Leave crap lying around on the stack (GS, Piet, etc) or in a consecutive (reachable) memory block (BF, etc) in a predictable manner.  For these later cases, explain the output.  In all cases, what you return / print / whathaveyou should be a straightforward representation of a partition of `n` into primes with fewer than 6 parts.

**Scoring**

This is code golf, smallest byte count wins.

**Bonus!** if the word 'goldbach' appears as a subsequence (not necessarily consecutive; just in order. Case doesn't matter) of your program subtract 8 points.  The code above is an example of this.

Comment: The first number to check, odd integer > 1, is 3. Which sum of primes produces 3? Don't I see the obvious?

Comment: The 'obvious' is linguistic.  Since 3 is prime, it's the sum of 1 prime.  Smartass response: Conway would say that 3 is the sum 7 + (-1) + (-1) + (-1) + (-1).

Comment: A single value is not a sum. I would suggest simply starting with values > 3 instead of introducing negative values.

Comment: [A single value is a sum.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum#Special_cases)  The comment about negative values was a smartass remark, as explicitly noted.

Comment: *"substring (not necessarily consecutive; just in order...)"*  This is called a [subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring#Subsequence).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 29

```
(#~y=+/@>),{5$<0,p:i._1 p:>:y
```

Assumes input is in `y`.  Value of expression is list of boxes of list of 5 primes or 0 that sum to `y`.

```
   y =. 16
   (#~y=+/@>),{5$<0,p:i._1 p:>:y
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------+------...
|0 0 0 3 13|0 0 0 5 11|0 0 0 11 5|0 0 0 13 3|0 0 2 3 11|0 0 2 7 7|0 0 2 11 3|0 0 3 0 13|0 0 3 2 11|0 0 3 11 2|0 0 3 13 0|0 0 5 0 11|0 0 5 11 0|0 0 7 2 7|0 0 7 7 2|0 0 11 0 5|0 0 11 2 3|0 0 11 3 2|0 0 11 5 0|0 0 13 0 3|0 0 13 3 0|0 2 0 3 11|0 2 0 7 7|0 2 0 ...
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------+------...
```

Not enough letters to earn any bonus points.

Comment: nicely done! I think no language could beat J at this challenge.

Answer (score 9):

#### *Mathematica*, 38

```
IntegerPartitions[n,5,Prime~Array~n,1]
```

Comment: Can't find a way thru WA ...

Comment: I've got access to Mathematica, and it worked on all the inputs I gave it.

Comment: imagine if the `IntegerPartitions` function was named `Goldbach`... ;)

Comment: @w0lf even so, it'd be 1 more than J >_>

Comment: @Rixius no, it would score **21** in that case, 8 *less* than J.

Answer (score 8):

### C, 192-8 = 184 chars

Contains "Goldbach" consecutively (excluding punctuation), and "Tao" as well.
When the sum is less than 5 primes (i.e. always), prints zeros (16 = `0+0+0+3+13`)
Read the number from standard input: `echo 30 | ./prog`.

```
#define T(x)for(x=0;x<=s;b=&x,c(++x))
G,o,l,d,*b,a;c(h)
{(*b-1?h<3:++*b)||c(*b%--h?h:++*b);}
main(s){
    scanf("%d",&s);
    T(G)T(o)T(l)T(d)T(a)o+G+l+d+a-s?0:exit(printf("%d+%d+%d+%d+%d\n",G,o,l,d,a));
}
```

Old version (179 chars), which can find only sums of exactly 5 primes (and therefore fails for x<10):

```
#define T(x)for(x=2;x<s;b=&x,c(++x))
G,o,l,d,*b,a;c(h)
{h<3||c(*b%--h?h:++*b);}
main(s){
    scanf("%d",&s);
    T(G)T(o)T(l)T(d)T(a)o+G+l+d+a-s?0:exit(printf("%d+%d+%d+%d+%d\n",G,o,l,d,a));
}
```

Explanation:
`c` sets `*b` to the next prime (including `*b` itself if it's prime).
`T` builds a for loop, which advances one of the variables `G,o,l,d,a` to the next prime.
Within all for loops, we check if the sum matches, and print&exit if it does.

Comment: `G,o,l,d,*b,a;c(h)` is a nice touch!

Comment: this fails for n=3

Comment: @boothby, you're right, it only finds some of 5 primes, not less.

Comment: user_unknown has a good solution for this: consider zero prime for the sake of the sum

Comment: @boothby, changed. Cost me more than I'd like, because my logic naturally treats 1 as prime, and when starting with 0 I need to skip it.

Answer (score 8):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 9 bytes

```
~+.ṗᵐl≤5∧
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9icmFjaHlsb2cy//9@Ky7huZfhtZBs4omkNeKIp///NzMx/1M)

```
~+.          Output (.) should sum to the input,
   ṗᵐ        consist of all primes,
     l≤5     and have length ≤ 5.
        ∧    (Don't unify that 5 with the implicit output variable.)
```

Comment: You can save a byte by changing the [order](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v07b5@HO6Q@3TsixMXvUsdzn/39zY8P/wQA). Also note that the question states that the input is odd

Comment: @H.PWiz And another one like [this](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v05b7@HO6Q@3TsixMXvUsfz/f3Njw//BAA).

Answer (score 4):

### Ruby <s>138</s> <s>124</s> 117 - 8 = 109

```
require'mathn'
def g(o,l=[])
p l if l.inject(:+)==o#db
(l.last||1..o).each{|d|d.prime?and g(o,l+[d])if l.count<5}
end
```

Call with `g(<number>)`.
Sample output:

```
[2, 2, 2, 2, 19]
[2, 2, 3, 3, 17]
[2, 2, 3, 7, 13]
...
```

Test: http://ideone.com/rua7A

Comment: Just putting `#db` on line 3 would be enough for the bonus: you'll get the `ach` from `.each`.

Comment: What do you mean 'fixed output format'?  This one's totally open -- you can nix the spaces if you like.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Great tip! I've edited my post. Thanks!

Comment: @boothby Thank you for noticing this. I saw the sample output and thought it was a requirement. I see now that output format is open. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

### PHP <s>143</s> 122 - 8 = 114

*EDIT: Saved a few bytes on output, removed the explicit function call.*

```
<?function g($o,$l,$d,$b){for(;$o>=$b=gmp_intval(gmp_nextprime(+$b));)echo$b^$o?$l<4&&g($o-$b,$l+1,"$d$b,",$b-1):"$d$b
";}
```

Unrolled:

```
<?
function g($o,$l,$d,$b){
  for(;$o>=$b=gmp_intval(gmp_nextprime(+$b));)
    echo$b^$o?$l<4&&g($o-$b,$l+1,"$d$b,",$b-1):"$d$b
";}
```

Call with `@g(<number>);` Sample output for `n=27`:

```
2,2,2,2,19
2,2,3,3,17
2,2,3,7,13
2,2,5,5,13
2,2,5,7,11
2,2,23
2,3,3,19
2,3,5,17
2,3,11,11
2,5,7,13
2,7,7,11
3,3,3,5,13
3,3,3,7,11
3,3,5,5,11
3,3,7,7,7
3,5,5,7,7
3,5,19
3,7,17
3,11,13
5,5,5,5,7
5,5,17
5,11,11
7,7,13
```

Comment: Hmm... your submitted code doesn't seem to work.  You've got a some funny stuff `~õ;}` at the end...

Comment: ~õ (chr(245)) is shorthand for "\n". In this instance, it's not actually necessary. I'll remove it from the solution.

Comment: code fails for n=3.

Comment: @boothby I don't believe it does. For n=3, it outputs the number 3, and then terminates (as there are no other sums of primes which are 3). What were you expecting it to produce?

Comment: I don't see any output.  Works fine for 5, 7, 9, 11.  http://ideone.com/cMNR8  Also, note that you're free to define the function and not call it.

Comment: I don't know what to say, other than that Ideone doesn't handle php correctly; I've noticed this on other problems as well. PHP 5.3.6 running under Windows 7, and PHP 5.4.3 running under Ubuntu 11.04 both produce the correct output. Not calling the function explicitly would save 17 bytes, if I could figure out a different way to work 'goldbach' in ;)

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby 2 -rmathn, 66 bytes - 8 = 58

```
g=->o,*l{o==l.reduce(:+)?p(l):l[5]||b=Prime.each(o){|x|g[o,*l,x]}}
```

Heavily based on GolfWolf's answer, but since it's 6 years old I'm going to post my own instead of nitpicking. Advances in technology include the stabby lambda, using `reduce` instead of `inject` for the free `d`, a terse way of stopping at partitions of 5, and `Prime.each(o)`, which iterates over all primes less than or equal to `o` (and furnishes an `ach`). Maybe in another 6 years there'll be a better way of using the `b`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Scala 137-8=129

```
def g(o:Int)={val l=0+:(2 to o).filterNot(d=>(2 to d-1).exists(d%_==0))
for(b<-l;a<-l;c<-l;h<-l;e<-l;if(b+a+c+h+e==o))yield{(b,a,c,h,e)}}
```

After boothby's hint: eliminated one function call, allow to interpret 3 as the sum of 3 and nothing, remove input from output - saves another 20 chars.

Bonus emphasizing:

> def **g(o**:Int)={val **l**=0+:(2 to o).filterNot(**d**=>(2 to d-1).exists(d%_==0))
>    for(b<-l;a<-l;c<-l;h<-l;e<-l;if(b+a+c+h+e==o))yield{(**b,a,c,h**,e)}}

Invocation and result:

```
println (l(17)) 
Vector((17,0,0,2,2,13), (17,0,0,2,13,2), (17,0,0,3,3,11), ...
```

The output repeats x for every list to sum up to x, and then shows the 5 summands. 0 for missing summand, i.e. 2+2+13.

Ungolfed:

```
// see if there is some x, such that o%x is 0.
def dividable (o:Int) = (2 to o-1).exists (x=> o % x == 0)

// +: is a kind of cons-operator for Vectors
def primelist (d: Int) = {
  val s = 0 +: (2 to d).filterNot (b => dividable (b))
  for (a <- s;
    b <- s;
    c <- s;
    h <- s;
    e <- s;
    if (a+b+c+h+e == d)) yield {(a,b,c,h,e)}
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Scala.  How does this get called?  Can you post a working example to http://ideone.com?

Comment: You better execute it on [simply-scala](http://www.simplyscala.com/) because it needs less boilerplate than IDEone. For invocation, `println (l(17))` for example. The output looks typically like `Vector((17,0,0,2,2,13), (17,0,0,2,13,2), (17,0,0,3,3,11)` and means: 17 is to be summed, and the summands are 0, 0 (zero means absence of summand) 2+2+13. The link to simply scala [is already documented on meta](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/202/373)

Comment: cool, thanks!  Looks like you can save a few characters: `yield{(d,a,...` -> `yield{(a,...` and by packing the definition of `g` into `filterNot(...)`.  However.  This fails for n=3.

Comment: Do `(2 to d)` instead of `(2 to d-1)`, but I don't agree that 3 is the sum of 3. If you sum up a Set, yes, it can be an empty set, or a Set consisting of one number. But building a sum which leads to n - I only change my code under protest.

Comment: As noble as your obstinate refusal to shorten your answer may be, your cause is undermined by your very answer.  You're returning lists whose sum is `3`.  One such should be `(0,0,0,0,3)`.

Comment: @boothby: That's what I meant by 'I change my code under protest' - It is your question, and you define the rules. I can disagree on the way to express the rules, but I understood what you want.

Comment: ah, fair enough, I misread your previous post.

Answer (score 1):

## MuPAD 113 - 8 = 105

```
g:=[0,ithprime(i)$i=1..n]:f:=_for_in:f(l,g,f(d,g,f(b,g,f(a,g,f(c,g,if l+d+b+a+c=n then print(l,d,b,a,c)end)))))
```

This version will also print all permutations of every solution:

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 7
0, 0, 0, 2, 5
0, 0, 0, 5, 2
0, 0, 0, 7, 0
0, 0, 2, 0, 5
...
```

And yes, it creates a way too long list `g`. Who cares? :-)

Ungolfed version:

```
g:=[0].select([$1..n],isprime):
for l in g do
  for d in g do
    for b in g do
      for a in g do
        for c in g do
          if l+d+b+a+c=n then print(l,d,b,a,c); end;
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't have access to mupad -- can somebody check that this works?

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 19 bytes (but very slow -- advice wanted)

```
ÆR;0x5Œ!ḣ€5¹©S€i³ị®
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wW5C1QYXp0UmKD3csftS0xvTQzkMrg4GMzEObH@7uPrTu////xgA)

```
ÆR;0x5Œ!ḣ€5¹©€i³ị®     main link, takes one argument N
ÆR                     get all the primes less than N
  ;0x5                 add zero, and then repeat the entire list 5 times
      Œ!               get all the permutations of this huge list (takes a long time!)
        ḣ€5            for each permutation, just take the first 5 numbers
                       (this gives us all possible length-5 combinations of the primes plus zero, with some repeats)
           ¹©          save that list to register
              S€       take the sum of every permutation in the list...
                i³     and find the index of our first argument N in that list of sums
                  ị®   then recall our list of permutations, and get the correct permutation at that index!
```

If you have any ideas to make it faster and shorter, please let me know!

Comment: [12 bytes](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9qZWxsef//w4ZS4bmXw5Digqw14bqOUz3CpcOQZv///zc). `ṗÐ€5` produces all combinations of primes with lengths one through five. `S=¥` checks if the sum of one of the elements is equal to the chain's argument and `Ðf` keeps only those elements. `Ẏ` is only there to put all lists of primes at the same level in the list

Comment: Now [10 bytes](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9qZWxsef//w4ZS4bmX4rGuNeG6jlM9wqXGh////zc) since `Ɱ` and `Ƈ` have been added as aliases for `Ð€` and `Ðf`

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 9 bytes

```
Ṅ'L5≤næA∧
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLhuYQnTDXiiaRuw6ZB4oinIiwiIiwiMjciXQ==)

Outputs all possible sums.

### Explained

```
Ṅ'L5≤næA∧   # Takes a single integer n and returns a list of lists
Ṅ           # Push all the integer partitions (ways to sum to) of n
 '          # and keep only those where:
  L5≤       #   the length of the partition is less than or equal to 5 (can also be 6<)
        ∧   #   and
     næA    #   all integers in the partition are prime
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 19 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Hideous, and slow as hell! Will crap out on inputs higher than 5.

```
ÆõÃc fj à l§5 æ@¶Xx
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=xvXDYyBmaiDgIGynNSDmQLZYeA&input=NQ)

```
ÆõÃc fj à l§5 æ@¶Xx     :Implicit input of integer U
Æ                       :Map the range [0,U)
 õ                      :  Range [1,U]
  Ã                     :End map
   c                    :Flatten
     f                  :Filter
      j                 :  Prime
        à               :Combinations
          l             :Filter by length
           §5           :  <=5
              æ         :Get the first to return true
               @        :When passed through the following function as X
                ¶       :  U is equal to
                 Xx     :  Sum of X
```